# Doctrine : Fetch "EAGER" and "Hydrate Array"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

With Doctrine, I have fetch=EAGER in my entity :

```
class TrainingOrganization
{
    /**
     * @var TrainingOrganizationVersion[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TrainingOrganizationVersion",
     *     mappedBy="trainingOrganization",
     *     cascade={"persist"},
     *     fetch="EAGER"
     * )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @Versionable
     */
    private $versions;
```

Why when i do "hydrate array" it does not work ?

Screen of my dump for same entity (Second is "Hydrate array") :

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please accept my answer. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Hydration mode `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY`, Doctrine will only return information about that 'row'. Since your `versions` attribute is not a field but a collection, it won't be returned.

If you want to have Collections included, use Objects instead (like your first screenshot).

If you really need your entities serialized (returning a multidimensional array instead of objects), use a serializer. Since you're using Symfony, you can easily use Symfony's [Serializer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html). The [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) is a popular alternative.